# How to make ItemMargin of CarouselControl adaptive in UWP?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I am working on a UWP app where my page has 2 columns. In the first column, I have used a Carousel Control to display different images. I would like to set the ItemMargin of the Carousel Control such that the second image just peeks enough to be seen by the user and I would like it to be adaptive such that the next image peeks in the same location of the column each time. Any ideas on how to go on about this?

Edit: Added a sample xaml code

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
  xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
  xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
  xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
  mc:Ignorable="d">

 <Grid>
   <Border Margin="0">
    <controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl"
              InvertPositive="True"
              ItemDepth="300"
              ItemMargin="336"
              ItemRotationX="-180"
              ItemRotationY="-180"
              ItemRotationZ ="-180"
              Orientation="Horizontal"
              SelectedIndex="0">
    <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
      <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut" />
    </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
        <Image Width="200"
              Height="200"
              VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
              Source="{Binding Thumbnail}"
              Stretch="Uniform" />
      </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
  </controls:Carousel>
</Border>
```

As you can see, I have fixed the value of ItemMargin to 336. However, when I resize this app, the position of the peeking image doesn't remain the same. I would like to have something where the position of the peeking image remains the same even when the app window is resized.

Comment: Hello, can you show some XAML code snippets or the effect pictures you expect? This will help us analyze your problem.

Comment: Added a sample added code in the above post

Comment: Hello, when you set `ItemMargin` to a fixed value, the control will not change adaptively. You can try to listen to the `Page.SizeChanged` event and dynamically modify the value of `ItemMargin` in code-behind.